# Global composite of radar data available?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, radar

[Iowa State offers an exceptional NEXRAD composite image as GeoTIFF for the entire continental US at a reasonable resolution.](http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/docs/nexrad_composites/) Is there a comparable GeoTIFF composite updated semi-regularly available for the entire world, or at least other major continental areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any, and I doubt there is a single source. You might be able to build one, but some places (e.g. [Australia](http://www.bom.gov.au/australia/radar/)) simply don't have full coverage.

Another option, if you just want global coverage (which pretty much means satellite) is to look at the [NASA MODIS](http://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/) layers. There is a lot of data, going well beyond the "pretty picture" level.